# how to use ORM with Java and MYSQL without hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, orm

```
public class DatabaseConnection {

 private final String CONNECTION_URI = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/justgolive";
 private final String DBUSER = "root";
 private final String DBPWD = "";

 private static DatabaseConnection conClass;

 private DatabaseConnection(){}

 public synchronized static DatabaseConnection getDatabaseConnection(){
    if(conClass == null){
        conClass = new DatabaseConnection();
    }
    return conClass;
 }

// Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
public synchronized JdbcPooledConnectionSource getConnection(){
    JdbcPooledConnectionSource  con = null;
    try {
        con =  new JdbcPooledConnectionSource (CONNECTION_URI, DBUSER, DBPWD);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return con;
}

/**
 * Close the database connection.
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public synchronized void closeConnection() throws SQLException{
    conClass.getConnection().close();
}

/**
 * Setup our database and DAOs
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public synchronized void setupDatabase() {

    try{
        // if you need to create the table
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(conClass.getConnection(), User.class);
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
       e.getMessage();
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }    
}

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //In a main() Method I do the following call:
        DatabaseConnection conDB = DatabaseConnection.getDatabaseConnection();
        JdbcPooledConnectionSource  con = conDB.getConnection();
        try
        {
        conDB.setupDatabase(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }// This call is the problem

    }
 }
```

This Error will shown when i run above code

```
2016-01-30 03:05:36,934 [INFO] TableUtils creating table 'accounts' 
2016-01-30 03:05:37,241 [DEBUG] JdbcPooledConnectionSource opened connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/justgolive got #1887400018 
2016-01-30 03:05:37,243 [DEBUG] JdbcPooledConnectionSource cache released connection @2f333739 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseConnection.compileStatement(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/j256/ormlite/stmt/StatementBuilder$StatementType;[Lcom/j256/ormlite/field/FieldType;)Lcom/j256/ormlite/support/CompiledStatement;     
at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doStatements(TableUtils.java:443)  
at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doCreateTable(TableUtils.java:428) 
at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:223)   
at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(TableUtils.java:61)     
at com.ORM.example.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Comment: There are many ORM without hibernate: Please adjust your question title. Also please add the table definition of the table you are trying to create (both from ormlite perspective as from database perspective).

Comment: Dear  i am use ormlite?? and i made a separate class User Class also @Norbert van Nobelen